# Selecting and Displaying MYSQL Column Name using PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I want to select and display the Column Name of my table. I used SHOW SQL Command to display the data to my select box. The problem is I want to omit Two(2) columns, ID and Image column to be exact. I have no problem with displaying all the column names. Please refer to my code below for more details.

PHP Code:

```
<?php 
    require "connect.php";

    $sql = "SHOW columns FROM tblLocation";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        echo "<option value='".$row['Field']."'>".ucfirst($row['Field'])."</option>";
    }
?>
```

Comment: `column to be exact` Not Understand

Comment: how can i skip it?

Comment: @TarangP "to be exact" is an idiom meaning "specifically". Those are the two columns he wants to omit.

Comment: make a array of the columns you want to show, compare it and show only matched

Answer (score 1):

use an `if` statement:

```
if ($row['Field'] != 'ID' && $row['Field'] != 'Image') {
    echo "<option value='".$row['Field']."'>".ucfirst($row['Field'])."</option>";
}
```

Comment: I worked, I just have one more question. How can I omit Two columns if i do not know what is the name of that column?

Comment: If you don't know their names, what criteria do you want to use to omit them?